# How to achieve overlapping cards in android jetpack compose with one card tilted a bit so user can know there is one more cards below?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-cardview

I am trying to overlap Cards on each other. There are two Cards , **card1** and **Card2**. So, I want to overlap them on each other in such a way that, user would know that **Card2** is below the **Card1** , so I want Card2 to be tilted on either side. I have written below code but it's showing Card2 only.
MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            OverlappingCardsTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    OverlappingCards()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun OverlappingCards(){
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){

        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(200.dp, 300.dp)
                .offset(40.dp, 40.dp),
            elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
                defaultElevation = 10.dp)
        ) {
            // Content of the first card
            Text(text = "Hello Card1")
        }

        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(200.dp, 300.dp)
                .offset(40.dp, 40.dp),
            elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
                defaultElevation = 10.dp)
        ) {
            // Content of the first card
            Text(text = "Hello Card2")
        }
        
    }


}



@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    OverlappingCardsTheme {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the rotate modifier to one of your cards modifier:

```
Card(
   modifier = Modifier
       .size(200.dp, 300.dp)
       .offset(40.dp, 40.dp)
       .rotate(10f)
   ...
)
```

I'd also slightly increase the elevation in the top card to make it a little more easy to stand out but depends on your UI

Comment: it's happening but I am not sure Why second card is on my first card? I want my second card to be below first

Comment: It's drawing the composables in the order they are inside the Box. The first is drawn first, and then the second will be drawn on top. So to change the order put the view you want on the bottom (your second card) before the view you want to be on top (your first card aka your last view to be drawn)